# Can we use uniqid() to generate a unique Salt in PHP

Tags: php, passwords, salt

I'm using bcrypt to hash my passwords. But I would like to use some Salt with it as well. Can I use the uniqid() function to generate a unique Salt for every user? Or may be something with more entropy like

```
uniqid('', true);
```

I do not understand many of the more complex ways of generating Salts. like using for loops and many different functions.

Thank you.

Comment: have a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4795385/how-do-you-use-bcrypt-for-hashing-passwords-in-php

Comment: Most BCrypt implementations will automatically generate a safe salt. PHP's new function [password_hash()](http://www.php.net/manual/de/function.password-hash.php) will for example read from the random source of the operating system. It is the best you can do, so you should not generate your own salt in this case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The purpose of a [salt](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Salt_%28cryptography%29) is to make it difficult to match the [hash](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hash_function). That being said this depends of the hash you're using and [how prone](http://www.math.dartmouth.edu/archive/m19w03/public_html/Section6-5.pdf) it is to [collisions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hash_table#Collision_resolution). Bcrypt is pretty strong [but it has its drawbacks](http://www.hashcollisions.com/2011/06/can-bcrypts-computational-expense-be-reduced-on-the-server-side/).

This code should make a 23 character salt [according to the manual](http://php.net/manual/en/function.uniqid.php).

```
printf("uniqid('', true): %s\r\n", uniqid('', true));
```

This gets you (256 bits) 64 digits:

```
hash("sha256",time());
```

Check-out [crypt](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.crypt.php) as well.

Using a SALT is always good because it makes it harder to find the original password (reverse engineer). That doesn't mean they can't get a hash collision that matches and allows them access if you're doing a match against a database. The longer the hash and the more character potential per position makes a collision that much harder and your system stronger (in theory).

Comment: @SameerZahid I wrote my response into my answer. Yes.